# NodeJs + Mysql query execution too late (delays)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mysqljs

NodeJs + Mysql query execution too late (delays)
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

Hello guys, I need help with mysql js, when I do .query(); the callback always delaying and gives me empty result but if I put timer it will give me the results, how do we fix the issue... on their documentation says this "Every method you invoke on a connection is queued and executed in sequence." so they using async i believe, anyone know how to wait for the results before sending data back to client side? I tried Promise, Async/Await but they using something else to stock up their queries..

```
con.query(`SELECT * FROM users`,
          function(err, data) {
            // this callback always delays 4 seconds, this callback executes straight away without waiting.
            return data;
          }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple options how to handle this case, I'd recommend you to wrap your query in Promise as following:

```
    function getUsers() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
            con.query(`SELECT * FROM users`,
            function(err, data) {
                if(err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                resolve(data);
            });
        })
    }

    //usage 

    async function(req, res) {
        try {
            const users = await getUsers();
            res.send(users);
        } catch(error) {
            res.status(500).send(error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the following file as `QueryRunner.ts` (Typescript). This will be your reusable component to run normal queries or parameterized queries. Then call 'executeQuery' function from your DAO layer as shown below.

```
export class QueryRunner {
private readonly connection: any;

constructor() {
    this.connection = require('mysql').createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: '3306',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'admin',
        database: 'quiz'
    });
};

public executeQuery(query:string, args?:any[]):any {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        this.connection.query(query, args,
        function(err, data) {
            if(err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            console.log('QueryRunner: data = ');
            console.log(data);
            resolve(data);
        });
    })
};}
```

=========================================

```
export class DAO {
private readonly queryRunner: QueryRunner;

constructor() {
    this.queryRunner = new QueryRunner();
}

public getUsers(): any {
    let query: string = 'SELECT name, role FROM user_master';
    return this.queryRunner.executeQuery(query);
}}
```